# PHP INCLUDE Not Working

Tags: php, html, include

The site [should look like this](http://sculptcoach.com/support.html). But I'm using PHP include (as I have on another site) to insert the header and footer (so I don't have to alter every single page when I want to make a change to one of them).

Right now, [this is what it's showing me](http://sculptcoach.com/). It's just not reading the PHP for some reason. The file names are right. There are about four different files I'm trying to call to that page.

Thanks for any insights!

Tara

Comment: Some code might be helpful...

Comment: And how do you expect us to help?

Comment: @AllisonC: Not really - if his code is not executed at all it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's a valid question - if you view source on the pages you can figure out PHP isn't getting processed (it shouldn't be in the final HTML).  I'd suggest removing the downvotes, because I would have been more upset if she just pasted all the HTML code in without knowing why she was doing it personally :) +1.

Comment: Thanks @W00te, I can't believe I'm getting called a troll for this? I thought people could just view the html source from the pages themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not working because you're trying to include PHP inside a .html file. Unless you've setup Apache to parse HTML as PHP then this will never work. If you don't have a PHP server you can often achieve a similar effect (common include files) with Server Side Includes (SSI).

FWIW you can tell that PHP isn't being parsed by the fact your PHP is just being output in the source code e.g.

```
<?php include('http://sculptcoach.com/sidebar.html');?>
```

Comment: The strange thing is it's working on my other site which is hosted on the same server: http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk

Comment: all down to how the accounts have been set up tbh. Likely there's a setting in httpd.conf or a .htaccess file

Comment: Thank you! It was the .htaccess file. I copied the old one over to my new site and it's working great now :) This is the line of code I think did it: Options +MultiViews
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

Answer (score 4):

PHP code is not being processed on the server side, I can see the code :

```
<?php include('http://sculptcoach.com/fbg.html');?>  
<?php include('http://sculptcoach.com/footer.html');?>
```

You can either configure your server to process HTML files as PHP scripts or change the files extensions to `.php`

Comment: Thanks @nacereddine, I tried this (changed .html to .php in index.html file, and on actual file names) and it hasn't had any effect.

What's really strange is that it works fine with my http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk site which is on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

note that you have an `index.html` and not an `index.php` 
probably you have to rename it from `.html` to `.php`

Answer (score 0):

This means PHP is not enabled on your server. Talk to whoever manages it and ensure they enable PHP for whatever file extension you are using (`.php` is the default nowadays).

Comment: Thanks @thiefmaster, but it seems to work fine on my other site which is hosted on the same server.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely a paths issue.  I'd recommend enabling seeing php errors so you could see exactly what is happening.